# Using HttpStatusCode 207 Multi-Status

Tags: c#, webdav, httpwebresponse

I'm doing a bit of WebDAV, and after my PROPFIND call I do something like

```
var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(propfind.ToString());
httpWebRequest.ContentLength = content.Length;
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";

// Get a reference to the request stream.
var requestStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
requestStream.Close();

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
{
    return response.StatusCode;
}
```

So I get this back and it's a 207. As I understand it a 207 is a positive thing, but I'd like to check this properly and handle errors more intelligently.

Can anyone tell me how I go about interrogating the `HttpWebResponse` better to confirm my PROPFIND was successful please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the response body (using `response.GetResponseStream()`) and parse the XML, which will contain the response codes.

The XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<a:multistatus
  xmlns:b="urn:uuid:c2f41010-65b3-11d1-a29f-00aa00c14882/"
  xmlns:a="DAV:">
 <a:response>
   <a:href>http://server/public/test2/item1.txt</a:href>
   <a:propstat>
    <a:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</a:status>
       <a:prop>
        <a:getcontenttype>text/plain</a:getcontenttype>
        <a:getcontentlength b:dt="int">33</a:getcontentlength>
       </a:prop>
   </a:propstat>
 </a:response>
</a:multistatus>
```

(according to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa142960%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx))